# Don't know how to re-build javascript file

Tags: cache, ee-1.13

## Problem

I'm currently seeing all of my javascript bundled into a single file, and then served from this file:  `$MAGENTO_ROOT/media/js/276342d53ebc2b88700c238821ff7e8d-v2.18.js`

I see this as a GOOD thing, however I'm not sure how to rebuild the file with updated code.

For example, I have a file in my source tree like this:

`/skin/frontend/responsive/<sitename>/js/<namespace>/<module>/<module>.js`

I can see that the contents of the `<module>.js` are embedded inside `276342d53ebc2b88700c238821ff7e8d-v2.18.js`, but for some reason when I make changes to `<module>.js` they aren't reflected in `276342d53ebc2b88700c238821ff7e8d-v2.18.js` even though I'm deleting it `276342d53ebc2b88700c238821ff7e8d-v2.18.js` completely.  It just re-appears.  So apparently there is some other temporary cache holding on to it?  I've even tried flushing all the caches in Magento admin including clicking the "Flush Magento Cache" button and the "Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache" button.  Still, the same .js is returned.

## Question

Any ideas?  Is there another directory on my disk that I should delete perhaps?

## UPDATE #1

I also tried turning off **System=>Configuration=>Advanced=>Developer=>Merge Javascript** but the file is still coming back as `276342d53ebc2b88700c238821ff7e8d-v2.18.js` when I fetch the page!

This brings up a related question. In my **System=>Cache Management** page, I see two buttons at the top "Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage".  The first one I've been using to flush the cache, but the second one has a warning "Cache storage may contain additional data. Are you sure that you want flush it?" so I've never actually done that.  What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

Try try to disable merge JS setting from **System=>Configuration=>Advanced=>Developer** and check if your updated js code is showing in particular JS file or not. 
Because Magento generally flush the merged JS/CSS cache when we use "Flush JsavaScript/CSS" cache button. So please verify first by disabling JS merging and let me know.

Comment: I've tried that now, and posted what happened as an update to my question.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: in case you didn't see it ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  It turns out there were actually 2 almost-identical versions of the same javascript file in my code base.  One was `xyz.js` and the other was `xyz.min.js`.  I'd been editing `xyz.js` since I could see the content served to the browser was not minified. Unfortunately neither file was really minified, and I had had just picked the wrong one.  I'll probably open another question to ask why there would be 2 files in the folder (in case this is some Magento convention I'm missing).